# OGG Vorbis in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, audio, ogg

I want to know if it's possible to play Ogg Vorbis audio file with iPhone SDK or if exist a library or a framework that allow this.

I've read something about OpenAL but I don't find any tutorial...
Can anyone help me??

Comment: [There may be a simpler way to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691510/ios-and-decoding-mp3-aac-data-from-memory-buffer)

Comment: This is quite late, but here is another question/answer with complete player using audio queues and libvorbisfile.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863811/how-to-use-audioqueue-to-play-a-sound-for-mac-osx-in-c/30756734#30756734

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Better late than never ;)**
I have found the answer here [Use cocos2d for playing ogg file in my project?](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15680).

> PASoundMgr is a different sound engine that had support for ogg file
>   playback. However, it hasn't been updated since iOS 2.x and there are
>   numerous issues that have cropped up since then that it doesn't
>   handle.
>
> Why do you need to play ogg files? If you convert them to aac you will
>   be able to play them back using hardware decoding which is much more
>   efficient from a cpu usage point of view.

They mentioned PASoundMgr. It worked for me. I just copied from cocos2d framework all files->libraries that *SoundEngineTest* was based on. And got rid of unnecessary code.

### Here is my [demoProject](https://code.google.com/p/play-ogg-vorbis-ios/) that shows how to play ogg on ios.

Be careful with iOS 5.* simulators, they have some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961840/what-does-this-gdb-output-mean) with sound library. My demo works on 4.3 simulator and on Device.

---

Here are steps that I made to create demo:

1. First you will need cocos2d-iphone framework. I've already had it, but you can find it here [cocos-2d_download](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download).
2. As you can notice *SoundEngineTest* depends on libvorbis.a. It's a library that made of files from `external/Tremor` group. Also it depends on OpenAl, AudioToolbox frameworks.
3. I copied all files from *tremor* group to my project. Crearted "vorbis" *Cocoa Touch Static Library*, without ARC. And added all source files and header to the "vorbis" target in *Build Phases* tab.
4. In the *Build Phases* of OggPlayDemo Added libraries (libvorbis, OpenAl, AudioToolbox) to the *Link Binary with Libraries* box.
5. Added *PA* classes to project. And checked OggPlayDemo as a target. To avoid problems with ARC, I disabled ARC compilation for this 3 *PA* files. (see [disable ARC for single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project))
6. Removed all cocos2d references. There were some code related to correcting position of listener depending on orientation... I commented it. I don't need this feature for just playing audio.
7. Copied audio file.
8. And finally added this code to ViewController:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       //init
       [PASoundMgr sharedSoundManager];
       [[[PASoundMgr sharedSoundManager] listener] setPosition:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
       self.audioSource = [[PASoundMgr sharedSoundManager] addSound:@"trance-loop" withExtension:@"ogg" position:CGPointMake(0, 0) looped:YES];

       // lower music track volume and play it
       [self.audioSource setGain:0.5f];
   }
   - (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
       [self.audioSource playAtListenerPosition];   
   }
   ```

Comment: By the way, I never used this for any of my projects, so I don't know if it's a good approach. But it works ;)

Comment: Worked for me but i had to change the int dst to long dst in PASoundSource.m

Answer (score 0):

[Cricket Audio](http://www.crickettechnology.com) will play ogg files, among others, and works on iOS/Android/WP8.