# iOS and decoding MP3/AAC data from memory buffer

Tags: iphone, ios

Forgive me, I very new at iOS - and programming at this scale in general.

I have been digging through iOS documentation, I know there are some functions like ExtAudiofile... for decoding MP3/AAC files, but are there any that will operate on Mp3/aac data that's already in memory?

I will probably have to extract the media data (byte by byte; iOS does allow that right?) from inside another file, so I can't just give it the URL.

Edit: the mp3 data will be in a non-standard file format, Apple provided function should not be able to read them. I heard iOS has a hardware decoder that works on one audio stream and the OS will fallback to software decoding if there are multiple streams.

I would rather use what Apple provides then integrate a MP3 decoder into the app.

Comment: It's pretty ambiguous what you're trying to achieve here. I suggest rewriting the question.

Comment: He's trying to get the raw PCM waveform data from an MP3 or AAC file.  The reason you would do this is compressed audio data (smaller download size) that still can be loaded into OpenAL (OpenAL requires decoded raw PCM waveform data).  [AVAudioPlayer does not apparently allow this](http://osdir.com/ml/coreaudio-api/2009-08/msg00093.html), but it may be possible to do this using this `ExtAudioFileRead` thing

Answer (score 7):

You can use ExtAudioFileRead to read a file that is in memory, but you have to use AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks. I'm not by my work computer so I can't give you exact code, but here's the general process:

- Use fopen/fread to read the given file into a memory buffer array. Use a simple C array and not an NSArray or NSData - you need speed and you need for it to be compatible with the next step.
- Create some basic C function callbacks for read / get size.
- Use AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks with the callbacks you wrote to open
  the audio file in memory.
- Use ExtAudioFileWrapAudioFileID to start decoding the file in memory.
  This is in replacement of ExtAudioFileOpenURL.

If you Google +AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks +ExtAudioFileWrapAudioFileID, you'll find that some folks have already done this and published their code.

I'm not sure what you mean by non-standard mp3 data, so you should try to play the file using another app to see if it will be compatible.

Comment: Fun, but googling your suggestion gives a whole page of this answer and the numerous sites that just copy stack overflow content.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting, it does. Try it without the plus' and the first result should be helpful:

https://github.com/sbooth/SFBAudioEngine/blob/master/Decoders/CoreAudioDecoder.cpp

Comment: The problem is that the mp3 stream size must be known... I need to decode a stream.