# play ogg in Xcode projects

Tags: audio, ogg, vorbis

I am developing an application in Xcode that need the ogg and vorbis framework to play ogg files. I have googled for some information about this but i didn't get to any point, i dont know how to make this framework to work. I have already downloaded the libraries and add them into my project but i dont get it to compile even when the files are already there it complains of missing files.

Can anyone point me to a good manual on how to accomplish this ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://meandmark.com/blog/2007/01/linking-external-libraries-and-frameworks-in-xcode/

Comment: This question seems to have a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745618/ogg-vorbis-in-iphone-sdk