# Playing an ogg stream in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, streaming, avplayer, ogg

Has anyone played an ogg stream from iOS? What can I use without having to write my own decoder?

I'm using Apple's AVPlayer to play the stream.

This question has been asked as part of this thread:
[iOS online radio streaming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830464/ios-online-radio-streaming-questions) but it hasn't been answered.

Comment: Checkout my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745618/ogg-vorbis-in-iphone-sdk/10176902#10176902). It's not about stream, but might be useful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no built-in support for playing ogg files in iOS, however, the source code for ogg compression/decompression is readily available (from [xiph.com](http://www.xiph.org/downloads/)). It is fairly straightforward to compile this code for iOS and use it in an app.

I had a chance to compile the libraries and have made them available: ["Precompiled Ogg Vorbis Libraries for iOS"](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/08/07/precompiled-ogg-vorbis-libraries-for-ios/).

I have also made some sample source code available on GitHub that shows how to play decoded Ogg Vorbis audio on iOS: [IDZAQAudioPlayer](https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer)

Comment: How can I use your Precompiled Ogg Vorbis libraries in iOS

Comment: How can I use your Precompiled Ogg Vorbis libraries in iOS

Comment: @user777304 You will need to use Audio Queues or OpenAL to play back the decompressed audio.

Comment: @user777304 Just put up some code on GitHub that demonstrates how to play back on iOS. See the link in my updated answer.

Comment: Is it possible to use AVAudioPlayer to play the decompressed audio? Your code is quite complex, I'm hoping I don't have to go that complex just to play a simple ogg file.

Comment: @rar Not really. You could decompress the entire file and play that view AVAudioPlayer, but that would introduce quite a log. The code I published is the simplest way (I know of) of pipelining the decompression and playback. Not sure why you think it is complex. Takes 4 lines of code to set up the player. Then you call things like [player play] and [player stop]!

Comment: @idz, really appreciate your effort to compile these libraries for armv7 and i386 platform. These precompiled libraries are missing arm64 and x86_64 architectures. I tried to compile these libraries unsuccessfully for these platforms. Were you able to compile these libraries for arm64 and x86_64 architectures/platforms?

Answer (score 2):

.ogg file may also be encoded in Opus or FLAC, refer to [Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) wiki. [IDZAQAudioPlayer](https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer) may not cover all cases.

For Opus codec, you may refer Telegram for iPhone source code: https://telegram.org/apps

Answer (score 0):

Use the [VLCKit](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit) – ibvlc bindings for macOS, iOS, iPadOS and tvOS in Objective-C.

It's a library from the well-known media player "VLC Media Player," and it supports Cocoapods and can play/stream .ogg files on iOS seamlessly.

```
  pod 'MobileVLCKit'
```

Check out [this blog post](https://ajith.blog/how-to-play-ogg-files-on-iOS-with-VLCKit) for a more detailed tutorial.