# Online streaming of .ogg audio file in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer

I want to play a .ogg audio file in iOS. This is the link of URL :-

http://strm.pistache.org:8443/pistache-tel.ogg

I have found some code from Github but that are not doing online streaming.
Can anyone knows the solution for playing .oog file from URL?

Comment: hope this helps ...similar  with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804046/playing-an-ogg-stream-in-ios

Comment: Thanks Sujania for reply, I have checked this but this is not playing ogg file from URL directly.

Comment: have u tried https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried but it play files only which are in my project. it crashes when i tried to play file from URL

Comment: @Singh did you solve this? I'm having trouble with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any Direct API of IOS to achieve this, but you can use some Library created to Play .OGG files or you can yourself made one of that using `ibvorbis 1.3.3`

Check out IDZAQAudioPlayer.
https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer

Comment: Actually, This is not play ogg file from URL directly.