# HTML Audio Won't Play on Mobile

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have an html audio tag and it works just fine on desktop browsers.  However, when I try to play it browsing on an iPhone (tried chrome, firefox, and safari), it just shows the pause button and nothing happens:

```html
<audio class="mt-3" controls preload="auto" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <source src="/media/example.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

[image: enter message here]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

.ogg files won't play natively on iOS as there is no built-in support. It will instead ask you to download the file (if you have storage to place it in).
Also see: [Playing an ogg stream in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804046/playing-an-ogg-stream-in-ios)