# How to use ogg.framwork in xcode to play audio from url or data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avplayer, ogg

From couple of days I was searching of how to play ogg on iPhone. But not successful. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804046/playing-an-ogg-stream-in-ios) which points towards [precompiled-ogg-vorbis-libraries-for-ios](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/08/07/precompiled-ogg-vorbis-libraries-for-ios/), but I don't know how to use this framework or libraries. I am new in coding. I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745618/ogg-vorbis-in-iphone-sdk?lq=1)
 but it plays ogg audio from bundle. I want to play from a given url, like wikipedia audios. any help will be great. Thanks

UPDATE:

I found another library or file which can be use in iOS but, still I don't know how to use in Xcode. [Ogg Vorbis I audio decoder by  Sean Barrett](http://www.nothings.org/stb_vorbis/). Any idea how to use this.

UPDATE 2:

Just tried to use it something like this, but output file have no sound. Any idea where I am going wrong.

```
NSString *file = @"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/En-us-Pakistan.ogg";
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file];

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
    unsigned char* array = (unsigned char*) [data bytes];
    int len = [data length];

    if (data != nil) {
        NSLog(@"\nis not nil");
        //NSString *readdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:(NSData *)data ];
        stb_vorbis* Stream = stb_vorbis_open_memory(array, len, NULL, NULL);

        if (Stream)
        {
            stb_vorbis_close(Stream);
            //return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //return false;
        }
    }

    Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);

    memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
    NSData *ddata = [NSData dataWithBytes:byteData length:len];

    if (ddata == nil) {
        NSLog(@"data nil");
    }
    else{


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"wikiaudio"];
    NSError *error;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder if it doesn't already exist

    NSString * filename = [@"hello" stringByAppendingString:@".mp3"];
    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", dataPath,filename];
    [ddata writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"filepath %@", filePath);
    }
```

Comment: Sample : https://code.google.com/p/play-ogg-vorbis-ios/

Comment: @Prince I tried it as I mention in my question. Does it be ok to use that in my project, does, apple will approve it???

Comment: yes apple will approve it

Comment: @user777304 were you able to convert .ogg file to any other format ?